# How to use module.exports with Barba

Tags: javascript, module

I'm trying to split my barba views into different modules with module.exports.

This is the code i have for the view.

```
var Barba = require('barba.js');

var HomeView = Barba.BaseView.extend({
  namespace: 'homepage',

  onEnter: function() {

    console.log('intro start home');
      // The new Container is ready and attached to the DOM.
  },
  onEnterCompleted: function() {
      // The Transition has just finished.
      console.log('intro finished home');
  },
  onLeave: function() {
      // A new Transition toward a new page has just started.
      console.log('outro start home');
  },
  onLeaveCompleted: function() {
      // The Container has just been removed from the DOM.
      console.log('outro finished home');

  }
});

HomeView.init();

module.exports = HomeView;
```

And this is how i am creating the module

```
var homeView = new HomeView();
```

The error i keep getting is 'i is not a constructor'.
I do this the same way with backbone views and this works.

Comment: Why are you executing `var homeView = new HomeView();`? Does `barba.js` documentation tell you to do this? I don't see anything like that. I'm removing backbone and nodejs because this question has nothing to do with them.

Comment: Ofcourse the Barba docs don't mention it because it's a nodejs feature to split up code with module exports.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should not do `var homeView = new HomeView();`, instead import the module and do `HomeView.init();`. These `barba.js` view's doesn't look like constructor functions that you manually initialize, they seem to find elements with matching namespace like

```
<div class="barba-container" data-namespace="homepage">
```

and create instances internally. Follow the documentation, it doesn't tell you to do `var homeView = new HomeView();`

Comment: It does not work like that.
Do you know how module exports work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm splitting by only importing the module (not creating a new instance) and it works:

```
import  HomeView from './your/path/HomeView'
```